# Why can't I call a parameterless func from inside AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, swift

This is really confusing! Why can't I call a simple parameterless constructor from within the AppDelegate in Swift language.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't call that function because it's not a class function - it's a function on an *instance* of the AppDelegate.

Whatever code is to the right of the equals of that let is executed before the object itself is actually instantiated. Thus, because the AppDelegate would not yet have been fully instantiated, the foo function is not available.